# FullCalendar agendaView not showing Sunday events

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I have a calendar of events using FullCalendar v.2.6.0. It pulls data from a JSON file that has 3 weeks of daily events. All the events, including Saturday events, display in the agendaWeek view expect Sunday events. Here is my setup

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        customButtons: {
        livePrograms: {
            text: 'All Live Programs',
            click: function() {
               window.location.href='https://mysite/live';
            }
        }
    },
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'livePrograms'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 'auto',
        allDaySlot: false,
        nowIndicator: true,
        events: {
            url: 'php/events.php',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });

});
```

Below is a snippet of my JSON data

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"51010",
      "title":"The Big Easy",
      "start":"Fri, 2016-01-01 00:00",
      "end":"Fri, 2016-01-01 02:00",
      "className":"hop",
      "url":"\/event\/41010"
   },
   {  
      "id":"91000",
      "title":"Creole",
      "start":"Fri, 2016-01-01 02:00",
      "end":"Fri, 2016-01-01 06:00",
      "className":"karma",
      "url":"\/event\/91000"
   },
   {  
      "id":"13240",
      "title":"People Presente",
      "start":"Fri, 2016-01-01 06:00",
      "end":"Fri, 2016-01-01 07:00",
      "className":"word",
      "url":"\/event\/13240"
   },
   {  
      "id":"47124",
      "title":"For Better or Worse",
      "start":"Sun, 2016-01-03 13:30",
      "end":"Sun, 2016-01-03 14:00",
      "className":"word",
      "url":"\/event\/47124"
   }
]
```

I have tried changing some of the settings including adding weekend: true in the config as well as creating a custom agenda view with a specified "duration: { days: 7 }," ... nothing seems to make a difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to add to this, when  I add a month view as default, and then go to the agendaWeek view, all events (yes including Sunday) appear.

Answer (score 1):

I used fullcalendar for my recent project. I used 0 instead of 7 for sunday. I think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change start, end date format in your json data.

Replace

```
"start":"Fri, 2016-01-01 00:00",
"end":"Fri, 2016-01-01 02:00",
```

with

```
"start":"2016-01-01 00:00",
"end":"2016-01-01 02:00",
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change. But I am still getting a blank on any event on Sunday